# Drupal-8 Call to a member function setRevisionable() on null

Tags: drupal-8, lightning

Currently I am working on Drupal-8.6.17 and Lightning 3.2.9

I am trying to update my lightning version 3.2.9 to 3.3.0(Core 8.6.17 to 8.7)
`taxonomy_term_field_data` table `status` value is already 1

Display the error while run `drush updb`

> Error: Call to a member function setRevisionable() on null in
>   /var/www/mysite/docroot/core/modules/taxonomy/taxonomy.post_update.php

**Reproduce Error Steps:**

```
composer require acquia/lightning:~3.3.0 --no-update
composer update
drush updb
```

Please suggest me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I am resolved this issue by checked not empty of `description` field.

Line no 172 on `/docroot/core/modules/taxonomy/taxonomy.post_update`

**Actual Code:**

```
$field_storage_definitions['description']->setRevisionable(TRUE);
```

**Changed to**

```
  if(!empty($field_storage_definitions['description'])){
      $field_storage_definitions['description']->setRevisionable(TRUE);
  }
```

It's working good to me. Cheers!